# I can't figure out why images and labels won't update in kivy

Tags: python, button, kivy, label

The full preamble is that I've been at this for about a month and have no idea what I'm doing. Further, I've tasked myself with figuring out kivy without using a kv file and it's just been going gangbusters. But to get down to brass tax, I'm presently working on a 'program' that:

1: changes a value with buttons

2: reflects those changes are on a Label

3: and changes an image based on what the value(s) is/are (sidelined @ present)

I have step one down, the value seems to change when I push buttons, according to the terminal, but those changes just aren't shown in the application, and I don't know how to ask the right questions to fix it. No holds barred, called me stupid till the code works.

```
class mainScreen(GridLayout):
    value1 = 20
    value2 = 15


    def sub(self, instance):
        self.value1 -= 1
        print(self.value1)
        print("you've done harm")
        return self.value1

    def add(self, instance):
        self.value1 += 1
        print(self.value1)
        print("You've done good")
        return self.value1

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(mainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        stat_num1 = NumericProperty(self.value1)
        stat_num2 = NumericProperty(self.value2)
        interface = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical")
        img = Image(source="graphics/healthy.jpg")
        """while self.value1 >= 15:
            img = Image(source = "graphics/healthy.jpg")
            if self.value1 <= 5:
                img = Image(source = "graphics/wounded.jpg")
            else:
                img = Image(source = "graphics/fine.jpg")"""

        b1 = Button(text = "up")
        b1.bind( on_press = self.add)
        b2 = Button(text = "down")
        b2.bind(on_press = self.sub)

        l1 = Label(text = "value 1: " + str(stat_num1))
        l2 = Label(text = "value 2: " + str(stat_num2))

        interface.add_widget(b1)
        interface.add_widget(b2)
        interface.add_widget(l1)
        interface.add_widget(l2)

        self.add_widget(img)
        self.add_widget(interface)



class pythonProject(App):
    def build(self):
        return mainScreen()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    pythonProject().run()
```

Comment: **First** of all kivy properties are supposed to be defined at [class level](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#observe-using-bind), **secondly** in order to observe any change in any property you have to bind it with some callback function, **thirdly** referencing widgets in `__init__` with `self` is very often a good idea and **lastly** always try to produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If you define `value` and `value2` as `NumericProperties`, you can define methods `on_value1()` and `on_value2()` that will get triggered when those values change. Those methods can then adjust the `Label` `text`. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class mainScreen(GridLayout):
    value1 = NumericProperty(20)
    value2 = NumericProperty(15)


    def sub(self, instance):
        self.value1 -= 1
        print(self.value1)
        print("you've done harm")
        return self.value1

    def add(self, instance):
        self.value1 += 1
        print(self.value1)
        print("You've done good")
        return self.value1

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(mainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        # stat_num1 = NumericProperty(self.value1)
        # stat_num2 = NumericProperty(self.value2)
        interface = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical")
        img = Image(source="graphics/healthy.jpg")
        """while self.value1 >= 15:
            img = Image(source = "graphics/healthy.jpg")
            if self.value1 <= 5:
                img = Image(source = "graphics/wounded.jpg")
            else:
                img = Image(source = "graphics/fine.jpg")"""

        b1 = Button(text = "up")
        b1.bind( on_press = self.add)
        b2 = Button(text = "down")
        b2.bind(on_press = self.sub)

        # save references to the Labels
        self.l1 = Label(text = "value 1: " + str(self.value1))
        self.l2 = Label(text = "value 2: " + str(self.value2))

        interface.add_widget(b1)
        interface.add_widget(b2)
        interface.add_widget(self.l1)
        interface.add_widget(self.l2)

        self.add_widget(img)
        self.add_widget(interface)

    def on_value1(self, instance, value):
        # gets called whenever value1 is changed
        self.l1.text = "value 1: " + str(self.value1)

    def on_value2(self, instance, value):
        # gets called whenever value2 is changed
        self.l2.text = "value 2: " + str(self.value2)


class pythonProject(App):
    def build(self):
        return mainScreen()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    pythonProject().run()
```

Comment: Sorry it has taken so long to respond. I've tried to understand what exactly is going on with the Numeric Property, in this particular demonstration, but it seems to go over my head.  but to see if I understand your example, setting a value with a NumericProperty makes it so that it makes a 'callback' on things with that value. So, I attempted to apply that to the image thing. but I don't think it's as simple as that and I'm not sure in what way.  I've combed over the documentation and find that it's still a little dense for me. assuming you're of the disposition, how does this work?

Comment: You've been immeasurably helpful regardless.

Comment: If you create a `Property` in a class (must not be created inside a method), then you can define a method of the form `on_<property_name>()`. That method will get called whenever that `Property` changes.